# ASP.NET Membership methods not working when on-premises app configured with Azure App proxy & SAML SSO

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory

In my MVC applications, below ASP.NET membership methods have been used:

```cs
Membership.GetUser()
Membership.GetUserNameByEmail()
Membership.FindUsersByEmail()
```

They are not working when I configure on-premises app with Azure App proxy and SAML SSO. But, when I debug locally, they are working fine.

They are returning null when I access deployed app.

I have used on-premises SQL Server.

Kindly let me know how to fix this issue.

Comment: The app is hosted on Azure and it's using on-premise SQL Server?

Comment: yes, app is hosted on Azure and it's using on-premise SQL Server present in onpremise network.